# Obtener propiedad de un objeto por uno de sus atributos

Tags: javascript, web, objeto

Digamos que tengo el siguiente objeto

```
const movementKeys = {
       
        w:{
            pressed: false,
            
        },
        a:{
            pressed: false,
            
        },
        s:{
            pressed: true,
            
        },
        d:{
            pressed: false,
           
        },
       keystate: {
        lastUpped: "",
        lastKey: ""

        }
    
    }
```

Una  de las teclas (la S) tiene su propiedad 'pressed' como true.
Hay alguna forma con la que pueda referirme a alguna de las letras basándome en si su propiedad es true o false?

Por ejemplo

```
movementKeys.???.pressed = true
```

Se que una de las letras. (w, a, s, d) solo UNA tiene su propiedad pressed en true, pero no se cuál. ¿Cómo averiguo cuál es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `for...in`:

```javascript
for(const propiedad in movementKeys) {
  if(movementKeys[propiedad].pressed == true) console.log(propiedad)
}

// output:
// s
```

> Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in